# What is the reason why this variabe change from main method is not effected on upper Class

Tags: java

Please forgive if it is too much of a novice question, but I need your help to understand why the call to b.createNumB(1) in the main method would effect the change on numB in ClassB.

```
class ClassB {
        int numB = 0;
        public int getNumB(){
            return numB;
        }
        void createNumB(int num){
            numB = num;
        }   
    }

    public class ClassA {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();

        // Returns numB from ClassA
            public int returnB(){
            return b.getNumB();
        }

         public static void main(String[]args){   
             ClassA a = new ClassA();
             ClassB b = new ClassB();

       //My espectation is that b.createNumB(1) should update numB in ClassA
             b.createNumB(1);
             System.out.println(a.returnB());
         }   
        }
```

The code when run prints 0 instead of 1; Please I need an explanation to what is
happening behind this code. thanks.

Comment: You are using different object references. The object declared in ClassA is not the one you are using when you set the value 1. You're using a local instance created in main.

Comment: Does this even compile? `createNumB` looka invalid. How can a int equal a type?

Comment: `Int` is no type/class whatsoever in Java.

Comment: Whoops nvm. `Int` should be lowercase, and have a more descriptive name, but that's besides the question. As the other commentor mentioned, you aren't changing the `ClassB` inside of the `ClassA`. There are 2 `ClassB`s being used in your program: the one inside of the `ClassA`, and one that you created inside the `main`. You're changing the one inside of `main`, then checking the one inside of the `ClassA`.

Comment: @Veluria I know, I deleted that comment.

Comment: @user3284549 thanks for educating actually forgot about objects features for a moment there. 5 months into learning and I think I need that patience now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wouldn't work because you are creating separate instances of `ClassB`. If you want this to work, you have to pass the instance to `ClassA`. Like this:

```
public class ClassA {
    ClassB b;
    public ClassA(ClassB b){
       this.b = b;
    }
//...
```

Then you can do do `ClassA a = new ClassA(b)`.

Changing one value of an instance doesn't affect all instances. You could do that if you used `static`. I think you could research `static` for yourself to learn.

Comment: A constructor of ClassA wtih ClassB object. Thank you Sir, just did that and it worked.. Apart from passing B object as argument or using a static b of B, can you suggest any other approach. Greatefull for pointing this out

Comment: @Nexima360 Passing an object of `ClassB` to `ClassA`'s constructor to be used internally is known as "dependency injection". If you don't #need# to pass it in, create it inside of `ClassA` so your user doesn't need to worry about it. That's part of the reason to use classes, to internally deal with initialization so the person using the class doesn't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Nexima360 Instead of passing a whole `ClassB` object in, you could pass the number to the `ClassA` object, and have it give it automatically to the `ClassB` object.

Comment: @Carcigenicate using classA and ClassB was just to understand what I was doing wrong, the moment you pointed out that they were two different object, I understood what it meant and made the correction. The class I am writting needed to pass it object without modification into classA, the the challange was that this object was not a static type and the only thing that came to my mind was to call it from the main method hoping it will affect it member object in classA which turned out to be a logical misconception of mine. Thanks for the help, was appreciated